# How to remove a section of data from XML without attributes in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

I would like to know what would be the best way to remove XML without without attributes in C# .NET. I am currently trying to use: System.Xml
and System.Xml.XPath but cannot get it to work.

```
    public String lstToTxt;
    private void delReminder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string lstIn;
        int intselectedindex = lstVxmlin.SelectedIndices[0];
        if (intselectedindex >= 0)
        {
            lstIn = lstVxmlin.SelectedItems[0].ToString();
            lstToTxt = lstVxmlin.Items[intselectedindex].Text;
        }


        Console.WriteLine(lstToTxt); //TEST: var returns e.g. = Green Mint

        //Delete XML.
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("Resources\\SavedReminders.xml");
        xdoc.Descendants("Reminder")
        .Where(x => (string)x.Element("PlantName") == lstToTxt)
        .Remove();
    }
```

The XML is below:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Reminders>
  <Reminder>
    <PlantName>Swedes</PlantName>
    <SowInDoorsDate>N/A</SowInDoorsDate>
    <SowUnderCoverDate>N/A</SowUnderCoverDate>
    <SowOutDoorsDate>12/02</SowOutDoorsDate>
    <PlantOutDoors>N/A</PlantOutDoors>
    <HarvestTimeDate>20/05</HarvestTimeDate>
    <Notes>N/A</Notes>
    <PlotNumber>0</PlotNumber>
  </Reminder>
    <Reminder>
    <PlantName>Green Mint</PlantName>
    <SowInDoorsDate>05/05</SowInDoorsDate>
    <SowUnderCoverDate>N/A</SowUnderCoverDate>
    <SowOutDoorsDate>N/A</SowOutDoorsDate>
    <PlantOutDoors>N/A</PlantOutDoors>
    <HarvestTimeDate>07/6</HarvestTimeDate>
    <Notes>N/K</Notes>
    <PlotNumber>0</PlotNumber>
  </Reminder>
  <Reminder>
    <PlantName>Turnips</PlantName>
    <SowInDoorsDate>05/03</SowInDoorsDate>
    <SowUnderCoverDate>N/A</SowUnderCoverDate>
    <SowOutDoorsDate>N/A</SowOutDoorsDate>
    <PlantOutDoors>N/A</PlantOutDoors>
    <HarvestTimeDate>07/4</HarvestTimeDate>
    <Notes>N/K</Notes>
    <PlotNumber>0</PlotNumber>
  </Reminder>
</Reminders>
```

Comment: Is a `xdoc.Save` call for the `XDocument` all that is missing?

Comment: Just tried the code, it works perfectly fine. If you look xdoc in the debugger after your last statement, you'll see that your node is missing in the in-memory XML. Looks like you're just not saving the XML back to the disk?

Comment: Will check it 2 secs.

Comment: Looks like that worked, don't know how I missed that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved `xdoc.Save();` was missing.